# Implicit function theorem for equation systems, 2nd derivative.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-function-theorem

The implicit function theorem says that if an equation system is given by $f(x,t)=0$ (where $x$ and $t$ are vectors, and where $f(x,t)$ is a vector of the same size as $x$)
then
$$Dx/Dt=-\operatorname{inverse}(Df/Dx)*Df/Dt.$$

For univariate systems this formula can be applied also to find higher order derivatives (e.g. http://www.informatik-forum.at/attachment.php?attachmentid=11423&d=1195488667). Does this work for multivariate systems as well?

Comment: it does. it is just nasty and less useful. Just differentiate $f(x(t), t) = 0$ twice or differentiate $-(D_x f(x(t), t))^{-1} D_t f(x(t), t)$ once.

Answer (score 0):

From $0=f(x,t)$ you get the first derivative by solving
$$
0=f_x(x(t),t)·x'(t)+f_t(x(t),t).
$$
Further differentiation of this equation gives an equation for the second derivative
$$
0=f_x(x(t),t)·x''(t)+f_{xx}(x(t),t)[x'(t),x'(t)]+2·f_{tx}(x(t),t)·x'(t)+f_{tt}(x(t),t)
$$
This can be continued for higher derivatives, restricted only by the smoothness of $f$. One has to observe the order of operands since the derivatives are matrices and tensors, thus unlike the scalar case not commutative.

Comment: Just to clarify: Here f_xx[x′,x′] is the second derivative of f wrt to x f_xx(x,t) evaluated at the values x=t=x′(x,t), while x' is the first derivative of x wrt t. Thanks

Comment: No, yes to second derivative, but it is a vector-valued bilinear form. The $x'$ are the arguments of the bilinear form, the directions of the derivative. At some point you have to change to some kind of tensor or multilinear notation.